# Not able to pass in values to docusign template

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to figure out how to pass in form field values to my docusign template. I looked at the v2 API docs but found nothing.

Comment: in my work with templates i had a similar question, maybe their response can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085916/inline-composite-templates

Comment: If all he's trying to do is populate form fields with values then `compositeTemplates` is probably a bit overkill...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just specify in your JSON request properties (or XML) by using the `tabLabel` and `value` properties.  For instance, this would populate 2 data fields, one named "ApplicantName" the second "ApplicantSSN"...

```
{
    "accountId": "221765",
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign Templates Webinar - Example 2",
    "emailBlurb": "Example #2 - Dynamically Populate Form Fields",
    "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "jondow@email.com",
            "name": "Jon Dow",
            "roleName": "RoleOne",
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantName",
                        "value": "John Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantSSN",
                        "value": "12-345-6789"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

For a full code walkthrough you can combine the above JSON with one of the sample code walkthroughs here:

[DocuSign API Walkthrough #1](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate)