# Can templates be used to send same PDF form filled with different data to different recipients

Tags: docusignapi

We want to integrate docusign functionality in our product where we allow our product users to map PDF Forms to database fields and populate the PDF form as per the mapping.

We want our users to populate PDF forms with appropriate data as per the configured mapping in our application, before they send the filled PDF form to get it signed from different associated recipients. Original PDF form will be same but its fields will contain different data as per the intended recipient.

We do not want users to repeatedly configure Signing Tabs (Tags) for the same PDF forms again and again.

So we thought trying Templates feature available in docusign. I just want to confirm before implementing Templates feature, whether Template feature will allow me to Send the same PDF form with associated recipeints data filled up from our application and send the filled PDF form to recipients to sign.

As per the documentation it is not clear, whether I can upload the document’s bytes of the document to be signed while using the template feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely populate different values for different recipients when using the same DocuSign template.  They would not be very useful if you could not.

This has been answered through other posts, see here for example:
[Not able to pass in values to docusign template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344441/not-able-to-pass-in-values-to-docusign-template/26353006#26353006)

You just need to use the `tabLabel` to identify the tab you want to populate and then use the `value` field to populate it's value dynamically.  For instance, to populate to two text fields (ie data tabs) you would do:

```
{
    "accountId": "221765",
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign Templates Webinar - Example 2",
    "emailBlurb": "Example #2 - Dynamically Populate Form Fields",
    "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "jondow@email.com",
            "name": "Jon Dow",
            "roleName": "RoleOne",
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantName",
                        "value": "John Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantSSN",
                        "value": "12-345-6789"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: I do not want to populate any values using tabLabel in docusign. My scenario is I have a blank PDF fillable form and I want to configure the balnk form as a template pre-configured with signing tabs where the recipient needs to sign the PDF form.

Comment: Then I will use the same fillable PDF form to populate values in the form fields from my application and send that populated PDF form to recipients for signing. It is like merging empty PDF form saved as a template and configured for signing tabs on docusign and same PDF form populated with values using my application and sending to recipients for signing. Is it possible to implement such scenario using template in docusign?